# How to fix signInWithPopup() about:blank pop up

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying out Firebase and its relative angular library angularfire2. All worked fine until i tried to add service workers and then deploy it to firebase (Before I deployied it on my personal website and it worked fine). Now, when I try to perform a Google login with the *signInWithPopup(provider)* a pop up opens but its blank and the page main reloads not completeng the method

There are the snippets:

**login-page.component.ts**

```
login() {
this.authSvc.loginG().then(res => {
  this.authSvc.person.ref.where("id", "==", `${res.user.uid}`).get().then(snap => {
    if (snap.empty) {
      this.openDialog(res.user.email, res.user.uid);
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");
    }
  })
})
.catch(error => {
  alert(error);
})}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
loginG() {
let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
return this.firebaseAuth
  .auth
  .signInWithPopup(provider)}
```

**EDIT:**

I diabled service workers and when i try to deploy it on my domain it works fine, but on firebase hosting and localhost(very strange) it keeps the error.

**EDIT 2:**

The problem can be fixed by removing the lazy loading and load the component directly, but if someone knows why this happen I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Please include any errors from the web console to help debug this issue.

Comment: @bojeil The console thorws no error because the page reloads before completing the operation